# Python AWS Lambda IndexError

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting this error while reading a CSV file with only 2 columns separated by a comma. The code is below , the error is on line 16 given in bold. I know the index starts at 0 and my file has 2 cols only , so what is the issue if i use 0 and 1 for reading the columns? Please clarify
error in line  **'Name':row.split(',')[1]**

```
import boto3    

s3=boto3.client('s3')

dyndb=boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def csv_reader(event, context):

    print(event)

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

    key  = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    obj  = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=key)

    file_content = obj['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")

    print(file_content)

    table = dyndb.Table('CSVTable1')

    with table.batch_writer() as batch:

        for row in file_content:

          batch.put_item(Item={

          'EID':row.split(',')[0],

          **'Name':row.split(',')[1]**

  })

    return 'Hello from Lambda'
```